# retrieve an nonexistent row as a NULL when JOINED

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I just want to know, how can I retrieve a non-existent row in a table and return it as NULL?

**Brief**

For example, in the code below it would only return a data that does exists in skill_players which is not the result that I want. What I want the result to be is, to output the existing data to have its value from **skill_players** if that doesn't exist then output the value as **NULL** so I could use **IFNULL** for later purposes.

**Table Design**

[skills_type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHnuE.png) table

[skill_players](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GcIGi.png) table

**Current result**

```
[Skill Name]        | [Value]
TotalStoreRobbed    |  8
```

**Expected result**

```
[Skill Name]        | [Value]
TotalRape           |  NULL
TotalBeenRaped      |  NULL
TotalRob            |  NULL
TotalBeenRobbed     |  NULL
TotalStoreRobbed    |  8
TotalCuffEscape     |  NULL
TotalArrest         |  NULL
TotalBeenArrested   |  NULL
```

**Code**

```
//fetching item data
$query =
"
    SELECT
        skill.value, type.skill_name
    FROM
        skills_player AS skill
    LEFT JOIN
        skills_type AS type
    ON
        skill.fk_skill_id = type.skill_id
    WHERE
        skill.fk_user_id = ?
";
if($stmt = $sqlHandle->prepare($query))
{
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $acc_ID);
    $stmt->execute();
    $res = $stmt->get_result();

    $skills = null;
    if($res->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
            $skills[] = $row;
            print_r($row);
        }
    }
}
else {
    $error = $sqlHandle->errno . ' ' . $sqlHandle->error;
    echo $error;
}
```

Thanks, Patrick!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the `WHERE` clause to the `ON` clause, and change the order of the join.  Left join skills to players, thus retaining all skills.

```
SELECT
    skill.value, type.skill_name
FROM
    skills_type AS type
LEFT JOIN
    skills_player AS skill
ON
    skill.fk_skill_id = type.skill_id AND
    skill.fk_user_id = ?
```

The problem with your current query is that, though it does use a `LEFT JOIN`, it will discard any records in the `skills_player` table which a given user does not have.  Instead, you want to show every skill record, regardless of whether or not a user has that skill.

Comment: Moving the ``WHERE`` clause to the ``ON`` clause, joins the data that aren't even related to that specific user_id, although it kinda does return NULL but to a row that isn't related to user_id. 

If I wasn't clear enough, I am trying to load all those fields from skills_type whether they exists in skill_players, if they do exist, return the value from the field and if they don't exist return ``NULL`` as a value.

Comment: @Patrick Sorry...I thought you already had the correct join order, which you did not.  You should be joining skills to players, in that order.